# Redirect output of a program that executes shellcode

Tags: c, bash, shell, io-redirection, shellcode

i have this little program that executes a shellcode:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char shellcode[]="here is the bytecode";


int main(int main, char *argv[]) {
      void (*ret)();
      ret = (void (*)())shellcode;
      (void)(*ret)();
}
```

i compile it with: `gcc -o file file.c -fno-stack-protector -z execstack`.
Then i try to redirect the output to a file: `./file > tmp.txt`
But it doesn't work. Neither this: `./file 2> tmp.txt` or `./file &> tmp.txt`

The output is always printed to the screen, never to the file. Can anyone help me? I really need the output of that shellcode.

Comment: What does the shellcode do? How does it print its output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If redirecting stdout and stderr doesn't work then the program is likely accessing the terminal directly. To capture direct terminal output you need to launch the program with a pseduo-tty connected. The easiest way to do that (that I'm aware of) is to use ssh. Try:

`ssh -qt localhost "./file" > tmp.txt 2>&1`

You'll want to install ssh keys to avoid having to enter login credentials.

Edit: Oops, my redirections were in the wrong order. Rookie mistake.